# how to connect with a SQL database and no sql database?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I was about to install mongodb Bundle and I tried to connect with 2 databases, one SQL and other NoSQL. I tried to generate getters and setters with this command 
`:php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents`

the problem is I got this message

```
error accès refusé pour l'utilisateur 'root'@'@localhost'
```

This is the part that added to `config.yml` in order to configure mongDB

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {} 
    default_database: ********
    document_managers:
        default: 
            auto_mapping: true
```

and this is my parametres.yml

```
parameters: 
    database_driver: ****
    database_host: ****
    database_port: *****
    database_name: ******
    database_user: *******
    database_password: ********
    mailer_transport: *****
    mailer_host: ******
    mailer_user: *****
    mailer_password: *****
    locale: *****
    secret: *********
```

Comment: `'root'@'@localhost'` typo maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set a username and password for doctrine_mongodb in config.yml?

```
# Doctrine MongoDb
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: %your_mongo_database_server%
            options:
                username: %your_mongo_database_user%
                password: %your_mongo_database_password%
                db: %your_mongo_database_name%
```

Comment: I have not added a username ans a password ! is it necessary ??

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not sure.

Comment: I tryed in local whitout options username and password and effectively it's not necessary but in my case my mongodb username and password are both set to null.
Have you ever succeed to connect to your mongodb ? with a terminal ?

Comment: yes it work a probleme of user and password in mongodb